# How to tell google that I accept cookies python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

I am trying to **accept cookies** and search in google. But I am facing a problem that I never faced before.
**Webdriver cant find the accept cookies button element**. I looked everything. **I tried to see if something changes the xpath**(Is there any thing triggers any other element so the xpath will change) but I have zero in my hand. I tried using `accept.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)` and `accept.click()`. Nothing seems to work.
What I have for now;

```
def GoogleIt():
path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver.get("https://google.com")
wait(5)
accept = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/c-wiz/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div/div[2]")
accept.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
accept.click()
search = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input")
search.click()
search.send_keys(talk)
```

Note: wait() is a different name of time.sleep()

**Error;**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Teknoloji\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/Teknoloji/Desktop/Phyton/Assistant V1/Assistant.py", line 20, in GoogleIt
    accept = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/c-wiz/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div/div[2]")
  File "C:\Users\Teknoloji\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Users\Teknoloji\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Users\Teknoloji\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Teknoloji\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div/c-wiz/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div/div[2]"}
  (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.121)


Process finished with exit code -1
```

If you need more information I am here.
**Thanks...**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To click on `accept cookies` button which is inside an `iframe` you need to switch to iframe first.

Induce `WebDriverWait()` and `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it()` and following css selector.
Induce `WebDriverWait()` and `element_to_be_clickable()` and following xpath.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[src^='https://consent.google.com']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@id='introAgreeButton']"))).click()
```

You need to import following libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what I was looking for.

Comment: I followed your suggestion, except in my case By.CSS_SELECTOR doesn't work. I have to use By.ID instead. It's a German website btw.

Answer (score 1):

After the latest update of Selenium, the above solutions did not work for me.

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

firefox_binary = FirefoxBinary()
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=firefox_binary)
```

Let's say you want to get this page from Google:

```
browser.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=cats&source=lnms&tbm=isch')
```

To continue, you have to click on "Accept all"

[image]

Then, you use Selenium to click the button:

```
browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"//.[@aria-label='Accept all']").click()
```

Then, you can continue to Google page!

Comment: SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//.[@aria-label='Accept all']' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//button[@aria-label='Accept all']").click()
works

Comment: I cannot explain how, but @tiagosilva last comment worked for me for a short while, but suddently stopped working. Is it still working for anyone?

Answer (score 0):

In case KunduK's solution doesn't work for some of those reading this, use "By.ID" parameter instead of the "By.CSS_SELECTOR" in the `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it()` method -

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "name_of_the_iframe")))
```